# Prevent fast double click on link button inside Repeater

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net

if I have fast double click call js function Show(), (show please wait), but doesnt call  the function vb.net  Button_Click.

Any idea how can I prevent this.

```
Thats my code:
```

ASPX

```
<ItemTemplate>
<span style="padding: 25px !important; display: inline-block;">



 <asp:LinkButton ID="butcarr" BorderStyle="None"
  runat="server" Width="230px"  CssClass="text-accent-bright btn-lg btn  border-gray btn-raised btn-labeled small-padding"
OnClientClick="return add(this)"
 CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Id").ToString() %>'
  OnClick="Button_Click">                               
  </asp:LinkButton>



 </span>
</ItemTemplate>
 <FooterTemplate></div></div></FooterTemplate>
 </asp:Repeater>
```

Javascript

```
function add(obj) {
            show();

             obj.disabled = true;


            return true;

        }


  function show() {           
 $find('<%= popup.ClientID%>').show();
        }
```

//server side

```
 Protected Sub Button_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    'do something

    popup.Hide()
       End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The rest of the `add()` function is never executed because in the first line you're calling `show()` where you miss a hash mark from your JQuery selector. And of course there's no show method of null. (Plus I think `$find` feels very weird. Not sure, it might work but I've never seen it like this.)

So your show function should be:

```
function show() {
    $('<%= "#" + popup.ClientID %>').show();
}
```

Comment: Hi, the rest of function with normal click is executed, the problem occurs when i have fast double click.